# field.setAccessible(false) effect on NON-private fields

Tags: java, reflection

What effect has `field.setAccessible(false)` on non-private fields?

**I expected that the access to this member is denied, but that's not the case!**

I tried to dig in the source-code, but at some point ([Field#getFieldAccessor(Object)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/reflect/Field.java#Field.getFieldAccessor%28java.lang.Object%29)) i lost track of what is happening.

I created a special class for this situation:

```
public class DemoObject {

    public Object publicMember = new Object();
    protected Object protectedMember = new Object();
    Object defaultMember = new Object();
    private Object privateMember = new Object();
    public final Object publicfinalMember = new Object();
    protected final Object protectedfinalMember = new Object();
    final Object defaultfinalMember = new Object();
    private final Object privatefinalMember = new Object();

}
```

And created a Demo:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class MyMain {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        DemoObject object = new DemoObject();

        System.out.println("'reflective' member access after field.setAccessible(false)");
        for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(false);
            try {
                System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " + field.get(object));
                // only throws exception for the privateMember and privatefinalMember
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        System.out.println("'reflective' member access after field.setAccessible(true)");
        for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " + field.get(object));
                // throws no exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
'reflective' member access after field.setAccessible(false)
publicMember: java.lang.Object@e9bfee2
protectedMember: java.lang.Object@237aaeec
defaultMember: java.lang.Object@4b721a26
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class MyMain can not access a member of class DemoObject with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.doSecurityCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at MyMain.main(MyMain.java:13)
publicfinalMember: java.lang.Object@7c30cd64
protectedfinalMember: java.lang.Object@67fc9fee
defaultfinalMember: java.lang.Object@7a67f797
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class MyMain can not access a member of class DemoObject with modifiers "private final"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.doSecurityCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at MyMain.main(MyMain.java:13)
'reflective' member access after field.setAccessible(true)
publicMember: java.lang.Object@e9bfee2
protectedMember: java.lang.Object@237aaeec
defaultMember: java.lang.Object@4b721a26
privateMember: java.lang.Object@424c2849
publicfinalMember: java.lang.Object@7c30cd64
protectedfinalMember: java.lang.Object@67fc9fee
defaultfinalMember: java.lang.Object@7a67f797
privatefinalMember: java.lang.Object@15e8f2a0
```

Comment: What are your conclusions?

Comment: i GUESS it does nothing. but i'm not sure! that's why i'm asking the question.

Comment: I meant: what are your observations after running your program?

Comment: could you explain -1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the documentation of [`AccessibleObject#setAccessible(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) method:

> A value of false indicates that the reflected object should enforce Java language access checks.

So, setting a `false` value doesn't mean that the field won't be accessible. It just means that the normal Java access rules will be enforced.

So, `public` members will be accessed as it is done normally. Same for `protected` members (They will be accessible in same package, and subclass in other package).

Comment: this is it! i was blind ;-)

Comment: and there is no other side effect?

Comment: @PhilippSander. I guess no. That method invocation is not really needed, unless you want to revoke the previously released restriction.